# Where is the best placement of the form to see a results?

Tags: usability, forms, labels, formatting

I am creating this form with the results to be shown, not really sure though if it is exact way to put at the right side.

[image]

Comment: I'm not really sure that I understand what you are asking. A lot of blurry text doesn't help me either. How about creating a mockup without blurry text and with the actual problem?

Comment: Blurry texts are for confidential purposes. I am just asking whats the best way to show the results. Anyway changed the image.

Comment: We need more context here. What are the results? What does the user have to do, or have done previously to see the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **General rule: Input on the left, output on the right.**

People read from left to right (excluding a few cultures). This means they will need to see the input, before they progress onto the results.

Therefore the form needs to be on the left-hand side, with the results appearing on the right-hand side.

Example: [FreshDesk help site](http://freshdesk.com/contact).

If you click the Support icon floating on the right-hand side of the page, you'll be presented with a grey box. If you enter information in the email and subject lines, the knowledge base on the right-hand side will automatically populate. This is a normal experience, as you're inputting as you're reading.

The alternative would mean reading the empty results column, filling in the information on the right and then moving back to the original results column - which is strange, as the user has already parsed that information as "not helpful" the first time they read it.

Comment: How about the applications from Adobe like Photoshop, Illustrator, etc.?